# pdf viewer impressive does not run on external screen

Tags: pdf, fullscreen

I want to use impressive as my default pdf viewer for presentations, but I cannot get it to run fullscreen on the external screen, i.e. the beamer.

evince will fullscreen on any screen that I drag the window on.

I use arch Linux with the openbox wm and manage my screens with xrandr/arandr if that makes a difference...

How do I get to run impressive in fullscreen on the beamer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in impressive's [FAQ](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/faq.php):

> Unfortunately PyGame, the windowing API currently used by Impressive, does not contain any support for multi-monitor setups whatsoever